# How to perform drag and drop operation in ListView with custom ListViewItem

Tags: listview, uwp, datatemplate, contenttemplate

I am developing a UWP application where I have implemented a listview with some datatemplates:

```
<Page
x:Class="ListView_DragDrop.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListView_DragDrop"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="StyleTile1">
        <Grid Height="100" Width="100" Background="Green" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="Grid_DragStarting" Drop="Grid_Drop">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="StyleTile2">
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200" Background="Purple" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="Grid_DragStarting" Drop="Grid_Drop">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="StyleTile3">
        <Grid Height="50" Width="50" Background="Red" AllowDrop="True" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="Grid_DragStarting" Drop="Grid_Drop">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="myListView" ReorderMode="Enabled" CanDrag="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile1}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile1}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile3" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile3}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile4" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile2}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile5" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile3}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile6" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile3}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile7" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile2}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile8" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile1}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile9" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile2}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tile10" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StyleTile1}" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And I want to perform drag and drop operation in it. Could you please let me know how to achieve the same?

Comment: What do you mean by drag and drop operations? Do you mean reordering list items via drag and drop? If yes then you should use uwp community toolkit it has a list control that does exactly this.

Comment: Did you check official [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop) ? Also you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt185571.aspx) and [here](http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/8/23/drag-and-drop-in-uwp)